# selenium find_element_by_css_selector for the long class name

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried multiple times with other instruction codes with space from the tutorial which worked fine. However, when I just changed the URL and the following class, it would give the error saying

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.88)
```

Everything worked when I used the tutorial code.

Here is my code (I have solved a few chrome driver problems from the internet)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://raritysniper.com/nft-drops-calendar")

time.sleep(1)

link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".w-full.h-full.align-middle.object-cover.dark:brightness-80.dark:contrast-103.svelte-f3nlpp").get_attribute("alt")

print(link)
```

I am trying to get attributes of each projects and make them into csv.
(Please refer to the screenshot)

[Screen shot of HTML that I am trying to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoVSB.png)

it would be wonderful if anyone could depict the problem I got with the code.

Thank you!

Comment: What webelement you are looking for using this locator `.w-full.h-full.align-middle.object-cover.dark:brightness-80.dark:contrast-103.svelte-f3nlpp` ?

Comment: a text ("alt") and a link for Img ("src"). but neither of them worked.

Comment: I see `alt` and `src` in the HTMLDOM. However my question was basically for which product/Imgae you want these two attribute value?

Comment: I eventually wanted to get all of them in the website. however, I wanted to see if I could get each of attirbute values into lists and loop them within the same class. I was going to use `find_elements_by_css_selector` once I see it working with the first one.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: @IshanShishodiya I want to get attributes that is under `.w-full.h-full.align-middle.object-cover.dark:brightness-80.dark:contrast-103.svelte-f3nlpp` class and put them into a list.

Comment: I can't find the CSS SELCTOR `.w-full.h-full.align-middle.object-cover.dark:brightness-80.dark:contrast-103.svelte-f3nlpp`

Comment: @IPLab-H: the below example to just retrieve info from the first element, as you've mentioned you would use `find_elements_by_css_selector` to get all of them in loop. I will leave that up to you. However do let me know in case you are looking for any other assistance.

Comment: @EL-AJIOussama I have add the screenshot for your reference! refer to the highlighted class

Comment: @cruisepandey Thank you so much for your answer. It did work! However, I did tried to use `find_elements_by_css_selector` with `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.w-full.h-full.align-middle")` It again did not work. I should take a deeper look into the method you've sugested. I will let you know if I need your assistance! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CSS_SELECTOR` that you are using

```
.w-full.h-full.align-middle.object-cover.dark:brightness-80.dark:contrast-103.svelte-f3nlpp
```

does not really match any element in the HTML.

Instead, you should use this `CSS_SELECTOR`:

```
div.w-full.h-full.align-middle img:not(.placeholder)
```

In code:

```
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://raritysniper.com/nft-drops-calendar")

#time.sleep(1)

first_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.w-full.h-full.align-middle img:not(.placeholder)")))
print(first_element.get_attribute('alt'))
print(first_element.get_attribute('src'))
```

**Import:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output:**

```
NEON PLEXUS
https://media.raritysniper.com/featured/neon-plexus_1648840196045_3.webp

Process finished with exit code 0
```